# Vector in an inverted frame of reference using Euler's Angles

Tags: vectors, rotation

Having some issues regarding the Euler's angles. Following is the short description of them problem.

In the first step, I determined the Euler's angles to invert my frame of reference that is X, Y and Z axes become -X, -Y and -Z respectively. I calculated the Euler's angles to be (135, 109.47, 45) in degrees for ZXZ scheme of transformation.

Now I expect that transforming any vector by same Euler's angles will invert it. For example, if I transform (1, 1, 1) vector with Euler's angles (135, 109.47, 45), I should get the vector (-1, -1, -1), but I find that it remains unchanged !!

Looking forward if someone can point out any discripancy in this process !

Comment: Euler angles concern a rotation performed by three succesive rotations. Inversion could not be performed by any number of succesive rotations.

Comment: Inversion is actually a scaling operation with $$ S = \left| \matrix{-1 & & \\ & -1 & \\ & & -1} \right| $$

Answer (score 0):

There is not single rotation that will invert *all* vectors. This is because the rotation preserved the components parallel to the rotation axis.

You know that three rotations about fixed axes (like ZYZ) is equivalent to a single rotation about an arbitrary axis. In your case, you have

$$ \mathbf{R} = \mathrm{rot}(\hat{z}, 135°) \, \mathrm{rot}(\hat{x}, 109.47122° ) \, \mathrm{rot}(\hat{z}, 45°) = \begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} \end{vmatrix} $$

The above is decomposed as follows:

$$ \begin{array}{r|l}
 \text{angle} & \theta = 180° \\
 \text{axis} & \hat{g} = \pmatrix{ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} } \\
 \text{quaternion} & \mathbf{q} = \cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\, \hat{g} = \hat{g}
\end{array} $$

So your Euler angles results in a rotation of 180° about an axis parallel to $\pmatrix{x=1&y=1&z=1}$. As a result, the components along this axis are *not* affected by the rotation.

Here are some examples of parallel and perpendicular vectors

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} \end{vmatrix} \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\1 } = \pmatrix{1\\1\\1} $$

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} \end{vmatrix} \pmatrix{1 \\ -1 \\ 0 } = \pmatrix{-1\\1\\0} $$

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} \\ \tfrac{2}{3} & \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3} \end{vmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ -1 \\1 } = \pmatrix{0\\1\\-1} $$